# i want to stop current playing audio when user click on next play button

Tags: java, android

I am facing problem in my app. All the audios are playing well but the problem is when I press on the first button to start playing audio, it plays it and if I click on next play button that also starts playing but the first audio does not stop. how to stop that. please help

[image]
Here, my app java code :

```java
    public class ringtone_tab extends AppCompatActivity {
```

...

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtone_tab);


            clk6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play6);

            clk5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play5);

            clk4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play4);

            clk3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play3);

            clk2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play2);

            clk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play1);



            mdx6 = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_vandana);

            mdx5 = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_tandav_mantra);

            mdx4 = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_shiv_om);

            mdx3 = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_shiv);

            mdx2 = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_aaradhna);

            mdx = MediaPlayer.create(ringtone_tab.this,R.raw.shiv_shankar);
        }


        public void setBtn_play6(View v)
        {



            if(mdx6.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx6.stop();
                mdx6.reset();
                mdx6.release();
            }
            mdx6 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_vandana);
            mdx6.start();

        }

        public void setBtn_play5(View v)
        {



            if(mdx5.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx5.stop();
                mdx5.reset();
                mdx5.release();
            }
            mdx5 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_tandav_mantra);
            mdx5.start();

        }



        public void setBtn_play4(View v)
        {



            if(mdx4.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx4.stop();
                mdx4.reset();
                mdx4.release();
            }
            mdx4 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv_om);
            mdx4.start();

        }

        public void setBtn_play3(View v)
        {



            if(mdx3.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx3.stop();
                mdx3.reset();
                mdx3.release();
            }
            mdx3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv);
            mdx3.start();

        }



        public void setBtn_play2(View v)
        {



            if(mdx2.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx2.stop();
                mdx2.reset();
                mdx2.release();
            }
            mdx2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_aaradhna);
            mdx2.start();


        }


        public void setBtn_play1(View v)
        {

            if(mdx.isPlaying())
            {
                mdx.stop();
                mdx.reset();
                mdx.release();
            }
            mdx = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shankar);
            mdx.start();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce new method call like `stopAllplayers`

```
private void stopAllPlayers(){

if(mdx1 != null && mdx1.isPlaying())
        {mdx1.stop();mdx1.reset(); mdx1.release();}
if(mdx2 != null && mdx2.isPlaying())
        {mdx2.stop();mdx2.reset(); mdx2.release();}
if(mdx3 != null && mdx3.isPlaying())
        {mdx3.stop();mdx3.reset(); mdx3.release();}
if(mdx4 != null && mdx4.isPlaying())
        {mdx4.stop();mdx4.reset(); mdx4.release();}
if(mdx5 != null && mdx5.isPlaying())
        {mdx5.stop();mdx5.reset(); mdx5.release();}
if(mdx6 != null && mdx6.isPlaying())
        {mdx6.stop();mdx6.reset(); mdx6.release();}
}
```

then call this method in all of your play methods.

```
public void setBtn_play6(View v)
    {
      stopAllPlayers()
      ........
```

do this for all setBtn_play1, setBtn_play2.....

Use below code with one media player

```
public class ringtone_tab extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button clk1;
    Button clk2;
    Button clk3;
    Button clk4;
    Button clk5;
    Button clk6;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtone_tab);


        clk6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play6);

        clk5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play5);

        clk4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play4);

        clk3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play3);

        clk2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play2);

        clk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play1);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    }


    public void setBtn_play6(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_vandana);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void setBtn_play5(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_tandav_mantra);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }



    public void setBtn_play4(View v)
    {
       stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv_om);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void setBtn_play3(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }



    public void setBtn_play2(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_aaradhna);
        mediaPlayer.start();


    }


    public void setBtn_play1(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shankar);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void stopPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {mediaPlayer.stop();}
    }

    }
```

Comment: it works but if I click on other buttons to play the app crash

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh i updated answer with null check now try it

Comment: again the app stops. It stops like if i hit on 1 button it plays then i click on 3 button it also plays but when i click on any button app crash

Comment: What is logcat when app crash ?

Comment: how to find logcat

Comment: open logcat window in bottom of android studio. There were red color line with error when app crash

Comment: the logcat list is updating continuously how to find which line is related to my app crash

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh it may be resource leak when u use 6 mediaplayer. Use one mediaplayer. I updated my code u can use it

Comment: one more problem when i press on different buttons to play audio 15 times, after that all buttons stops to play any audio. Buttons start to play audio only if the app is restarted

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh is it now working correctly ? until you click 15 times. try to add  mediaPlayer.reset(); mediaPlayer.release(); to stopPlayer method

Comment: Thank you very very very very very much. I am very happy. I am trying to make an app. I stuck on this problem and maybe I will again be stuck on any code. GOD BLESS YOU 

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh please accept the answer and upvote it. Happy coding :D

Comment: I have upvote the above code added by you and also approved as the answer. Is it ok?

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh yeah totally fine.